Having error while creating new bench in frappe
continuously having error like " There was a problem while creating bench_name ".
tried everything but didnt change. also it is saying yarn error.
although I created a bench and if I close the cmd prompt then it shows the bench afterwards.

Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Share the entire command & its output. Your post does not provide sufficient information for anyone to help. Read this guide to understand how to provide context effectively when asking for help.
